# How can I transpose a table and make aggregation at the same time in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I a beginner with SQL. I wrote code for pivoting my table (from column view to row view). It works fine.

My query takes a 2 rows x 195 columns and converts it into a 195 rows x 3 columns.

```sql
select Element = [Key]
    ,New = max(case when time_index=1 then value end)
    ,'Current' = max(case when time_index>=2 then value end)
From  (
    Select [time_index]
            ,B.*
        From  (select * from ifrs17.output_bba where id in (618830,618686)) A
        Cross Apply (
                    Select [Key]
                        ,Value
                    From OpenJson( (Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper ) )
                    Where [Key] not in ('time_index')
                    ) B
    ) A
Group By [Key]
```

In the query you can read "(618830,618686)". It corresponds to the exctraction of two lines.

| time_index | legal_entity_code | cohort | ... | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | 50 | ... | ... |
| 2 | BBB | 55 | ... | ... |

TO

| Element | time_index_1 | time_index_2 and more |
| --- | --- | --- |
| legal_entity_code | AAA | BBB |
| cohort | 50 | 55 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... |

I would like now to add a third line (or even more) in my input table and make a sum by time_index. (Example: if two lines have time_index = 1, these two lines should be aggregated. Meaning that the values are aggregated and the characters flagged as "NULL".)

| time_index | legal_entity_code | cohort | ... | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | 50 | ... | ... |
| 2 | BBB | 55 | ... | ... |
| 2 | CCC | 45 | ... | ... |

to

| Element | time_index_1 | time_index_2 and more |
| --- | --- | --- |
| legal_entity_code | AAA | "NULL" |
| cohort | 50 | 100 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... |

How can I proceed?

Comment: `CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN...) > 1 THEN NULL ELSE...`?

Comment: I'm a little lost.  You say that the query produces 195 rows with 3 columns.  Then you should example data with 2 rows and a bunch of columns (more than 3).  I don't follow what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's attempt.

But summing the numbers is kinda problematic if you don't know their datatypes.
In the test below there's a TRY_CAST to a decimal.
And I doubt you want to sum the id's.

> ```
> create table yourtable (
>  id int primary key, 
>  time_index int, 
>  legal_entity_code varchar(30),
>  cohort decimal(2,0),
>  other1 nvarchar(5)
> )
>
> insert into yourtable 
> (id, time_index, legal_entity_code, cohort, other1) values
>   (618830, 1, 'AAA', 50, 'X1234')
> , (618686, 2, 'BBB', 55, 'Y5678' )
> , (618144, 2, 'CCC', 45, 'Y5678' )
> ```

> ```
> with DATA as (
>   select * from yourtable
>   where id in (618830, 618686, 618144) 
> )
> select 
>   [Key] AS [Element] 
> , [TimeIndex1] = max(case when time_index = 1 then value end)
>
> , CASE 
>   WHEN [Key] IN ('id')
>     THEN string_agg(case when time_index >= 2 then value end,',')
>   WHEN count(distinct case when time_index >= 2 then value end) = 1
>     THEN max(case when time_index >= 2 then value end)
>   WHEN sum(1-isnumeric(value)) = 0 -- numbers
>     THEN cast(sum(case when time_index >= 2 then numeric_value end) as nvarchar(30))
>   END AS [TimeIndex2Plus]
> from  (
>     select [time_index], B.*
>     , try_cast(value as decimal(20)) numeric_value
>     from DATA AS A
>     cross apply (
>        select [Key], [Value] 
>        from OpenJson( (Select A.* For JSON Path, Without_Array_Wrapper ) )
>        where [Key] not in ('time_index')
>     ) B
> ) C
> Group By [Key]
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Element           | TimeIndex1 | TimeIndex2Plus
> :---------------- | :--------- | :-------------
> cohort            | 50         | 100           
> id                | 618830     | 618686,618144 
> legal_entity_code | AAA        | null          
> other1            | X1234      | Y5678
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b5425c5c20191d69e6f480cf8b968f4f)*